# The type of a struct that conforms to a generic protocol with an associated type that is also a protocol

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols

This is very hard to put into words but I've created a minimal example.

Here is a gist if you'd prefer... https://gist.github.com/anonymous/67d83fb2f286cf84539b58be96a971d3

**The "data item" protocol**

I have a protocol which defines `Sortable` objects with a property `number` like so.

```
protocol Sortable: Comparable {
    var number: Int {get}

    static func < (lhs:Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
    static func == (lhs:Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
}

struct BasicSortable: Sortable {
    let number: Int

    static func < (lhs:BasicSortable, rhs: BasicSortable) -> Bool {
        return lhs.number < rhs.number
    }

    static func == (lhs:BasicSortable, rhs: BasicSortable) -> Bool {
        return lhs.number == rhs.number
    }
}
```

**The "worker" protocol**

Then I have a protocol that can do something with these `Sortable` types. But because it has a Self requirement it needs to be defined as a protocol with an associated type and in the structs as generic property...

```
protocol Sorter {
    associatedtype Item: Sortable

    func sort(items: [Item]) -> [Item]
}

// Two different sorters
struct AscendingSorter<T:Sortable>: Sorter {
    typealias Item = T

    func sort(items: [T]) -> [T] {
        return items.sorted()
    }
}

struct DescendingSorter<T:Sortable>: Sorter {
    typealias Item = T

    func sort(items: [T]) -> [T] {
        return items.sorted{$0 > $1}
    }
}
```

**The handler**

Finally a struct that pulls everything together...

```
struct DataHandler<T: Sortable> {
    let items: [T]
    let sortedItems: [T]

    init(unsortedItems: [T]) {
        items = unsortedItems

        let sorter = AscendingSorter<T>()
        sortedItems = sorter.sort(items: unsortedItems)
    }
}
```

**Making it all work**

This all works.

```
let array = [
    BasicSortable(number: 1),
    BasicSortable(number: 8),
    BasicSortable(number: 13),
    BasicSortable(number: 3),
    BasicSortable(number: 4),
    BasicSortable(number: 14),
    BasicSortable(number: 5),
    BasicSortable(number: 12),
    BasicSortable(number: 3),
]

let handler = DataHandler(unsortedItems: array)

handler.sortedItems
```

This prints out the array of items in the correct order depending on what type of sorter I create in the Handler

**The problem**

What I'm trying to do now is to find a property declaration for this `sorter` struct that can take ANY Sorter type into it but everything I have tried in doing that has failed so far.

Is there a way to do this?

In the struct I'd like to have...

```
let sorter: SomeTypeHere
```

And then in the init set it like...

```
sorter = AscendingSorter()
```

but no combination I have tried in doing this has worked.

Thanks

Comment: Does the `Sorter` protocol need to have an `associatedtype`? Why not make the `sort(items:)` method generic (i.e `func sort<T:Sortable>(items: [T]) -> [T]`)? In other words, does each instance of `AscendingSorter` or `DescendingSorter` need to have a single concrete type of  `Sortable` that it can sort? Although that being said, does the `sort(items:)` method even need to be an instance method – I can't see why you'd need to utilise any instance state.

Comment: @Hamish oh, I see. Hang on. I'll give that a go.

Comment: BTW, Swift 2.3 doesn't have a problem with the code you've posted above.

Comment: @NRitH the code I posted works. But try to save the sorter into a property that can take either the `AscendingSorter` OR the `DescendingSorter`.

Comment: @Fogmeister I guess my suggestion didn't work?

Comment: @Hamish I tried it... hang on. I'll update you.

Comment: @Hamish hey, sorry. Yes, it did work. I got distracted half way through implementing it but in the end it works. I even get the homogeneity from the fact that `Sortable` has the self requirement so even though the sorter doesn't have a type the array passed in can only be of one type anyway. Thanks. I'll have to consider both approaches before choosing one to go with. They both provide the same function and I think yours is possibly a little simpler.

Comment: @Fogmeister Ah okay, good to hear :) I have posted my suggestion as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use type erasure to implement your own `AnySorter`.

Starting with your own code from above:

```
protocol Sortable: Comparable {
    var number: Int {get}

    /* as Hamish mentions in his answer: 
       < and == already blueprinted in Comparable and Equatable */
}

protocol Sorter {
    associatedtype Item: Sortable

    func sort(items: [Item]) -> [Item]
}
```

Construct an `AnySorter`:

```
struct AnySorter<Item: Sortable>: Sorter {
    private let _sort: ([Item]) -> [Item]

    init<S: Sorter where S.Item == Item>(_ sorter: S) {
        _sort = sorter.sort
    }

    func sort(items: [Item]) -> [Item] {
        return _sort(items)
    }
}
```

Which you make use of e.g. as an argument to the initializer in your `DataHandler`:

```
struct DataHandler<T: Sortable> {
    let items: [T]
    let sortedItems: [T]

    init(unsortedItems: [T], sorter: AnySorter<T>) {
        items = unsortedItems
        sortedItems = sorter.sort(items: unsortedItems)
    }
}
```

Your handler can now be used with a type erased `AnySorter` applied to your `Sortable` types. E.g., for the two simple sorters you've supplied in your question:

```
struct AscendingSorter<T:Sortable>: Sorter {
    typealias Item = T

    func sort(items: [T]) -> [T] {
        return items.sorted()
    }
}

struct DescendingSorter<T:Sortable>: Sorter {
    typealias Item = T

    func sort(items: [T]) -> [T] {
        return items.sorted{$0 > $1}
    }
}

/* example usage */ 
extension Int: Sortable {
    var number: Int { return self }
} 

let arr = [1, 4, 2, 8, 3]

let dataHandlerDesc = DataHandler(unsortedItems: arr, sorter: AnySorter(DescendingSorter()))
print(dataHandlerDesc.sortedItems) // [8, 4, 3, 2, 1]

let dataHandlerAsc = DataHandler(unsortedItems: arr, sorter: AnySorter(AscendingSorter()))
print(dataHandlerAsc.sortedItems) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 8]
```

---

Edit addition to answer your comment:

> Is it possible to take the input parameter and store it in a property?
>   Would I just use `AnySorter<T>` as the type of the property?

Yes, you can keep a property in `DataHandler` with type `AnySorter`. E.g., for a contrived example, we can let `sortedItems` be a computed property that makes use of an `AnySorter` instance to sort a stored list of items (of course in reality we don't want to do this re-sorting for each call, but for this example only!):

```
struct DataHandler<T: Sortable> {
    let items: [T]
    var sortedItems: [T] { return sorter.sort(items: items) }
    var sorter: AnySorter<T>

    init(unsortedItems: [T], sorter: AnySorter<T>) {
        items = unsortedItems
        self.sorter = sorter
    }

    mutating func changeSorter(newSorter: AnySorter<T>) {
        sorter = newSorter
    }
}

/* example usage */ 
extension Int: Sortable {
    var number: Int { return self }
} 

let arr = [1, 4, 2, 8, 3]

var dataHandler = DataHandler(unsortedItems: arr, sorter: AnySorter(DescendingSorter()))
print(dataHandler.sortedItems) // [8, 4, 3, 2, 1]

dataHandler.changeSorter(newSorter: AnySorter(AscendingSorter()))
print(dataHandler.sortedItems) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 8]
```

Comment: OK, I like this :D Is it possible to take the input parameter and store it in a property? Would I just use `AnySorter<T>` as the type of the property?

Comment: @Fogmeister sure, I added an example of such a case.

Comment: Excellent, thanks :D This will allow me to do what I wanted including default value for the sorter and other things like that :D Thanks

Comment: @Fogmeister happy to help!

Comment: Just to check. This AnySorter declares a private function _sort that essentially redirects to the sort function of the concrete Sorter that is passed into the init method...? Right? That's cool, thanks :D Also, just checked... the type of the sorter is inferred from the first parameter of the init method so the <Int> isn't required in your example :D

Comment: @Fogmeister Yes, the `sort` method of the `Sorter` instance is "stored" in the `AnySorter` (as closure member property `_sort`: closures are reference types so I guess `_sort` keeps a reference to the `Sorter` argument's `sort` function: so one could say this backend reference still remember the `Sorter` type, but that wont reach us in `AnySorter`), whereas the information of what type the actual `Sorter` instance was is lost after initialization (hence termed type erasure). Ah, Swift can infer the `AnySorter` generic from the first array argument to the initializer, neat, thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 3):

If an instance of a given type that conforms to `Sorter` can deal with any homogenous array of elements that conform to `Sortable` (if it's restricted to a single concrete type, then [@dfri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39478180/2976878) has got you covered) – then `Sorter` need not have an `associatedtype` in the first place. You could simply make the `sort(items:)` method generic instead, which would allow you to use `Sorter` as a type.

Also if your `sort(items:)` method doesn't utilise any instance state (it doesn't in your example code), then you could make it `static` – and simply pass around the types of sorters, instead of instances.

For example, your `Sortable` protocol, and `BasicSortable` implementation:

```
protocol Sortable : Comparable {
    var number : Int { get }

    // note that you don't need to re-define the < and == operator requirements,
    // as they're already defined by Comparable and Equatable
}

struct BasicSortable : Sortable {

    let number : Int

    static func < (lhs:BasicSortable, rhs: BasicSortable) -> Bool {
        return lhs.number < rhs.number
    }

    static func == (lhs:BasicSortable, rhs: BasicSortable) -> Bool {
        return lhs.number == rhs.number
    }
}
```

Your `Sorter` protocol, and different sorter implementations:

```
protocol Sorter {

    // A sort function that can take any homogenous array of a given
    // Sortable element (meaning that an instance of a type that conforms to
    // Sorter isn't restricted to a single concrete type of Sortable).
    // As the function doesn't rely on any instance state, it's static.
    static func sort<T:Sortable>(items: [T]) -> [T]
}

// Two different sorters
enum AscendingSorter : Sorter {
    static func sort<T:Sortable>(items: [T]) -> [T] {
        return items.sorted(by: <)
    }
}

enum DescendingSorter : Sorter {
    static func sort<T:Sortable>(items: [T]) -> [T] {
        return items.sorted(by: >)
    }
}
```

And finally, your `DataHandler` with an example usage:

```
struct DataHandler<T: Sortable> {

    let items: [T]
    private(set) var sortedItems: [T]

    var sorter : Sorter.Type { // simply hold a given type of sorter
        willSet {
            if sorter != newValue {
                // re-sort items upon (different) sorter being set
                sortedItems = newValue.sort(items: items)
            }
        }
    }

    init(unsortedItems: [T], sorter: Sorter.Type) {
        items = unsortedItems
        self.sorter = sorter
        sortedItems = sorter.sort(items: unsortedItems)
    }
}

let items = [BasicSortable(number: 2), BasicSortable(number: 4), BasicSortable(number: 6),
             BasicSortable(number: 1), BasicSortable(number: 4)]

var handler = DataHandler(unsortedItems: items, sorter: AscendingSorter.self)
print(handler.sortedItems)

// [BasicSortable(number: 1), BasicSortable(number: 2), BasicSortable(number: 4),
//  BasicSortable(number: 4), BasicSortable(number: 6)]

handler.sorter = DescendingSorter.self
print(handler.sortedItems)

// [BasicSortable(number: 6), BasicSortable(number: 4), BasicSortable(number: 4),
//  BasicSortable(number: 2), BasicSortable(number: 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I like the idea of using the static method and passing in the type rather than an instance. I've removed the declaration of the < and == I wasn't thinking straight when I added those. Of course the Comparable adds them :D I also like the use of the `willSet` trigger on the sorter. Thanks :D I've gone from almost giving up to two great answers in less than an hour :D #winning!

Comment: @Fogmeister Glad to be of help :)

Comment: Neat! Now indeed a very thorough combined answer to OPs question :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `sorter` property can't be declared as a regular `Sorter` because, as you pointed out, it has a `Self` requirement, but I believe you can do it if you add a second type argument to your `DataHandler`, so that it looks like

```
struct DataHandler<T: Sortable, S: Sorter> {
    let items: [T]
    let sortedItems: [T]
    let sorter: S

    init(unsortedItems: [T], sorter: S) {
        items = unsortedItems

        self.sorter = sorter
        sortedItems = self.sorter.sort(items: unsortedItems)
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem I have there is that the Sorter S no longer knows what types of items it is working with. So it won't accept the `unsortedItems` as a parameter in the sort function.